# How to add URL link in a SharePoint list?

Tags: list, publishing-site, datasheet

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template.

I am using List Web Part with Data Sheet view. I want to know how to make a column as a URL link (i.e. show text in the cell, and can associate a link with the text in each row for the specific column), i.e. when user clicks the text in the specific column of a specific row, the user will be directed to the link associated the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be best trying it as a dataview web part in SharePoint designer

Comment: "trying it as a dataview web part in SharePoint designer" -- could you describe in more details to try what?

Comment: Cool, question answered!